# Use SQL to display subtotals by a given data element

Tags: sql

I have a database filled with Twitter data that has had some sentiment analysis done.  I would like to build an SQL query that lists the relative counts of how the sentiment was analyzed for each location

Ideally the results would look something like:

```
TWEET_LOCATION   POSITIVE   NEGATIVE
Boston, MA           2846       5039
Chipotle             2846       5039
Orlando, Fl          2846       5039
```

Except that the number would be the number of positive and negative tweets for each location and not the overall total number of positive and negative.

My existing attempt is below:

```
SELECT   TWEET_LOCATION, 

    (SELECT COUNT(DEFLATE_SENTIMENT)    
    FROM DEFLATEGATE    
    WHERE  DEFLATE_SENTIMENT = 'positive' 
    OR DEFLATE_SENTIMENT = 'slightly positive') as Positive,

    (SELECT COUNT(DEFLATE_SENTIMENT)    
    FROM DEFLATEGATE    
    WHERE  DEFLATE_SENTIMENT = 'negative'
    OR DEFLATE_SENTIMENT = 'slightly negative') as Negative
FROM DEFLATEGATE    
GROUP BY TWEET_LOCATION
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Also I think I can figure out how to do it using a select case statement, but my teacher wants us to use a nested subquery.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, your `ORDER BY` doesn't make sense, unless `count` is a column in your table.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting help as well - this is my first question!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT TWEET_LOCATION
       SUM(CASE WHEN DEFLATE_SENTIMENT IN ('positive',  'slightly positive') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_positive,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DEFLATE_SENTIMENT IN ('negative',  'slightly negative') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_negative
FROM DEFLATEGATE    
GROUP BY TWEET_LOCATION;
```